# How to use a filtered member in a mapped type in a submap

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Ok, so I'm trying to create an API package. The API is described in a type like this

```
export interface ApiMethods {
  "rtm.auth.getToken": {
    requestArgs: {
      frob: string;
    };
    responseArgs: {
      auth: {
        token: string;
        perms: string;
        user: User;
      };
    };
  };
  "rtm.auth.getFrob": {
    requestArgs: Record<string, string>;
    responseArgs: {
      frob: string;
    };
  };
  "rtm.tasks.getList": {
    requestArgs: {
      list_id?: string;
      filter?: string;
      last_sync?: string;
    };
    responseArgs: {
      tasks: {
        list: TaskList[];
      };
    };
  };
}
```

I then want to create a mapped type that takes the above, parses the string keys and creates a hierarchical object type with methods inside namespaces. Here is what I've come up with so far

```
export type ApiSurface = {
  [K in keyof ApiMethods as K extends string
    ? GetStringBeforePeriod<GetStringAfterPeriod<K>>
    : never]: K extends string
    ? {
        [K in keyof ApiMethods as K extends `${GetStringBeforePeriod<K>}.${GetStringBeforePeriod<
          GetStringAfterPeriod<K>
        >}.${string}`
          ? GetStringAfterPeriod<GetStringAfterPeriod<K>>
          : never]: (args: ApiMethods[K]["requestArgs"]) => SuccessResponse<K>;
      }
    : never;
};
```

But try as I might, I can't get it quite right. At the moment, the generated object has the correct namespaces, and all the functions are created with the right names, but the inferred type places ALL the functions on both the namespaces.

It strikes me that I want to use the K in the second line (which I think I've successfully reduced to target the namespace, so 'auth' in the conditional within the second mapped type. But my brain is starting to hurt just trying to even read this. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Apart from the described issue, it looks like some types are missing (such as `GetStringBeforePeriod`, `GetStringAfterPeriod`, and `SuccessResponse`) which will prevent compilation. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77399663/edit) the question to include a [mre], ideally including a link to the reproduction in the [TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/we82gW).

Comment: Yes, please [edit] to provide a [mre] which defines everything you are using (what's `User`? what's `TaskList`?), including the expected type for `ApiSurface` so we can have something to work toward.  Like, **does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAPavN) meet your needs**?  If so I could write up an answer (after you edit to match). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, this did the job after a few tweaks @jcalz. I'll update the question shortly